# Get request with Python 2.7

Tags: python, authentication, get

I'm trying to send a get request with python 2.7. The server I'm trying to access has basic authentication and the url I'm accessing is just displaying a string I want my script to print that string.

So basically my code is sending a get request to this server and it saves the string it receives from the server, which also has basic auth.

The problem is that it prints out the html page for the login page not the string.

```
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

server = "http://someserver/update"

def get_auth():
    request = urllib2.Request(server)
    base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
    request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
    result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    # print(result)

def get_string():
    f = urllib2.urlopen(server)
    print f.read()

def main():
    get_auth()
    get_string()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: it only prints out the login page, i want it to go to the string. If i use postman /browser i get the string

Comment: are you sure it's actually logging in?

Comment: still an unclear question. Reading your code, it's obvious that it's printing the login page, because that's what you are **requesting**

Comment: @user2266449 Yeah i think thats the problem, it must be something to do with the login

Comment: @yzT It redirects to the login page /login. The problem im having is to have it print the /update page

Answer (score 1):

They way you are using `get_string()` never actually sends the authentication header.

Rather than fiddling with `urllib2`, you might want to try the `requests` library instead::

```
import requests
requests.get('http://someserver/update', auth=('username', 'password'))
```

see: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/

Comment: That works, but im using python 2.7 and i prefer not using requests.
Is there an alternative method than this?

Comment: requests is the tool to use here. That you are using 2.7 has no relevance to requests